# MS-Access: Parent-Child Relationships: It shows me ALL the children. How to filter parents based on children

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, master-detail

So let's say you create an AWESOME relationship between suppliers and products, you get super-cool stuff like this when you view the **normal Table**:

```
ID   SupplierName
1    Toys R Us
          ID   ProductName       Price
      |---6    Easy-Bake Oven    $15.00
      |---9    Bathtime Barbie   $12.00
2    Burger King
          ID   ProductName       Price
3    Dial-A-Widget
          ID   ProductName       Price
      |---3    Spanner           $5.00  
      |---19   Wrench            
4    Wendy's
          ID   ProductName       Price
5    Red Lobster
          ID   ProductName       Price
6    Kmart
          ID   ProductName       Price
      |---8    Blow-up doll      $55.00
      |---93   Collapsible Tent  $35.00
```

BUT there's a problem...
**What if I want to FILTER the parents based on the children???**
What if I don't want to see the suppliers that have no products?
Or what if we only want to see Suppliers that have products with no prices:

```
2    Dial-A-Widget
         ID   ProductName       Price
     |---3    Spanner           $5.00  
     |---19   Wrench
```

You get the idea.

A query doesn't show the parent-child / master-detail way like the normal Table-View does.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Select * from parent
inner join child
on parent.parentID = child.parentID
where child.productname is not null

Or something like that.  Purely "aircode" above, but you get the idea.

Comment: Nope, that puts them all in one record, instead of a master-detail like we want.
This is what it would output:
  ID   SupplierName  Product.ID   ProductName  Price

Comment: Maybe it needs to be Select Parent.*, Child.* from...  That should give you everything, and you're using the join to determine which records to keep.